# Is there a way to increment a number using CSS3?

Tags: css, stylesheet, css-transitions

I'm very familiar with JavaScript, and I realise I can do this with JS, but I don't want to -- I'd rather be able to do it in CSS, or not do it at all, since I stick with the rule that CSS is for presentation.

Nevertheless, I was wondering if there was a way to increment a number in a DIV progressively. So if I update a DIV's integer value from, for example, 1 to 5, then it would display 2, 3, and 4 before eventually stopping on 5.

In pseudo-code, I imagine it would be something like the following:

```
div.number
{
    // Increment by 1 step every 0.1 seconds.
    transition: increment(1) 0.1s
}
```

I don't think there is a way to do this in CSS3, but I'm curious as to just how powerful CSS is.

Comment: perhaps take a look at Less? http://lesscss.org - it allows for dynamic content inside of CSS files

Comment: @jpea: Less does not add any functionality that cannot be accomplished with more-complicated CSS.

Comment: If you are changing the content of something, then you're already out of presentational territory. Unless the number you're referring to is generated content?

Comment: @SLaks - your comment is intended as a joke, no? That's the whole point of Less. It does things to shorten your workflow in CSS by not having you create complicated CSS.

Comment: I'm changing the content using JS, but I would assume the incrementing is more presentational, as a *sort* of transition.

Comment: @jpea: But it cannot help you do anything that is impossible in CSS.  (such as changing content)

Comment: gotcha - I mis-read the OP - I thought they were looking for the equivalent of div_1, div_2, div_3{display:none;} or similar

Comment: @Wildhoney: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @jpea: That's quite all right! I will just stick with my earlier assumption that this just isn't possible in CSS at the moment, but hopefully one day my dreams will come true.

Answer (score 1):

Make an ordered list with a large number of `display:none` items, followed by one visible item (which will be numbered one)

To increment the number, change one `<li>` to `display: block`, but use `position: absolute` to make it invisible.  This will increment the number of the displayed item.

Comment: That's a quirky solution you have there! I can't quite picture it in my mind though. Could you knock up a quick JSFiddle for me please? If that's not asking too much.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to animate it.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit recently added support for CSS variables:
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/
and 
http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/css-variables-webkit-brings-the-css-jackalope-to-life/

That might be on the way towards a solution.

Pair it with a pseudo selector like

```
div:clicked {
   webkit-var-transformlen: 1
}
```

And it may work similarly to how you want.

Comment: The WebMonkey article was an interesting one to read, and I'm looking forward to this functionality in CSS! At the present moment I use LESS to provide variables and other such fancy things. However, I don't *quite* see how this would help with dynamically changing the content. If you could please shed some light on this, then that'd be wonderful...

Comment: I've updated the answer to include my original thought process. I'm just guessing here and haven't done any testing but I would be interested to know if this works.

Comment: Definitely! It's quite a cunning idea. Do the nightly builds of Chrome currently support the variables? Because at the moment I'm unable to test it.